# Can I tell Django to run some function after a file is uploaded through admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I have models like this:

```
class NameReplacements(models.Model):
    excel_file = models.FileField(upload_to='excel_files')

class NameReplacement(models.Model):
    name_to_replace = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    name_to_replace_with = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```

I am uploading the file for `NameReplacements` through admin panel.

Elsewhere in my app I have some code that reads the file from the latest instance of this model and saves data from each row of this file as `NameReplacement` instance:

```
def remove_old_name_replacements():
    '''Removes all instances of NameReplacement from database'''
    replacements = NameReplacement.objects.all()
    replacements.delete()

def import_name_replacements():
    '''Imports name replacements to database from last uploaded Excel file'''

    remove_old_name_replacements()

    replacements = NameReplacements.objects.last()
    df = pd.read_excel(replacements.excel_file.path)

    for i in range(len(df)):
        name_to_replace=str(df.loc[i, 'managers']),
        name_to_replace_with=str(df.loc[i, 'best_matches'])
        name_replacement = NameReplacement(name_to_replace, name_to_replace_with)
        name_replacement.save()
```

Currently I just run `import_name_replacements` manually from the Django shell whenever I upload a new file.

Is there a way to tell Django to run this code automatically whenever I upload the file via admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to well understand how the uploading process works.
But what you could do is to call the import_name_replacements method each time you create a NameReplacements object, to do this, you need to override the save method, here is an example:

```py
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(NameReplacements, self).save(**kwargs)
        import_name_replacements()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your NameReplacements model, which will override the save() method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NameReplacements, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    import_name_replacements()
```